# Calling a REST service from JBPM over a proxy

Tags: rest, service, task, jbpm

Calling a rest service (hosted on internet) from JBPM REST service task, JBPM server is behind proxy and cannot do the name resolution with local lan DNS. I have tried adding httpProxy settings and a specific name server spi but name resolution still fails.

Any thoughts?